# Android: Launch app with shortcut, perform action, and exit?

Tags: android, android-activity, shortcut

I have an Android application that can perform certain actions. However, I also allow the creation of shortcuts on the homescreen to perform certain things. There is a certain thing you can do in the app by pressing a button in it which calls a method (lets call the method DoAction), that I want to allow users to do directly from a shortcut. When clicking the shortcut, it opens the main activity and calls DoAction just as the button does, and then calls finish() on the activity to close it.

However, a problem arises when the app is already open in RAM (minimized). After calling finish() in the activity created by the shortcut, the old running instance of the app is brought to the front (which I don't want to happen).

How can I get around this?

Comment: how are you creating the shortcut? If you are using an Intent to do that try adding SINGLE_TOP flag. Or perhaps CLEAR_TOP, or CLEAR_TASK

Comment: Thanks! I used the ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK flag and it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you add the source code that you are using now as an answer to this question so that it can help people in the future with the same issue. Abstract the names of stuff if you have to to keep your stuff confidential but since it helped you it is bound to help someone else in the future if you post it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the working code I used to create the shortcut:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(ShortcutActivity.this, com.example.myproject.ClassToOpen.class);
shortcutIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); // This was the line that I needed to add

ShortcutIconResource iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(ShortcutActivity.this, R.drawable.shortcut);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Shortcut Name");
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```